# WPF MVVM async worker methods with cancellation/overlapping call handling

Tags: .net, wpf, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a detail view (for a list selection) that loads data from a database and I wan't to avoid any blocking by moving the database logic away from the UI Thread.

Issues:

- Make it async (the easy part, dispatch the logic that updates the viewmodel property(es) on the UI part when done)
- Handle when the user (eg. holding Down-Key) issues loading new entries before the background thread is done with the last entry

  - In this case the previous load methods should be cancellable (e.G. CanellationToken)
  - The result of calls that were started for the old selection must be discarded and not reach the UI, especially since that could overwrite the up-to-date data if the call finishes after a load operation that was started later

How to do that with WPF? If there is no built-in way my thought would be to make a class for that and use it for these kind of load methods in the viewmodel. e.G. pseudocode of two variants that come to mind

```
    public class ViewModelBackgroundLoader<TInput, TResult>
    {
        public ViewModelBackgroundLoader(Func<TInput, CancellationToken, TResult> loadFunc, Action<TResult> uiContinuation)
        {
        }
        public void Load(TInput input)
        {
            // set cancellation for previous loadFunc
            // async await loadAction on threadpool thread
            // If not cancelled... 
            //   uiContinuation() on UI thread
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelBackgroundLoadedProperty<TInput, TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModelBackgroundLoadedProperty(Func<TInput, CancellationToken, TResult> loadFunc)
        {
        }
        public TInput Input
        {
            set
            {
                // set cancellation for running loadFunc
                // async await loadAction on threadpool thread
                // If not cancelled... 
                //   Update Result property and fire propertychanged (in UI thread)
            }
        }
        public TResult Result { get; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple if you use a helper class I wrote called [`NotifyTask<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async):

```
public class ViewModel<TInput, TResult>
{
  private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

  public NotifyTask<TResult> Operation { get; private set; }

  public void Load(TInput input)
  {
    if (_cts != null)
      _cts.Cancel();
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Operation = NotifyTask.Create(loadFunc(input, _cts.Token));
  }
}
```

Data binding can be done to `Operation.Result` (and there are other data-bindable properties to easily show/hide loading indicators, etc).

The `CancellationTokenSource` thing is as you described, to cancel the previous operation (if any). There's no need to explicitly check and avoid UI updates from old operations because `Operation` is always overwritten as soon as a new one starts (so old data can never be shown - even if not cancelled, it would just be ignored).